# how to write an `Invert` type in typescript to invert the order of tuples

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-level-computation

```js
type a = [1,2,3]
type Invert<T extends any[] & {'0': any}> = ???
type b = Invert<a> // should yield [3,2,1]
```

I am stucked to figure out the definition of `Invert` type of a tuple,
also an `Init` and `Last` type, although they may be constructed of each others

what I have tried:

1. position the type in a function param definition and infer the `Rest` part, this approach only got the `Tail` part with rest params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as of typescript 4.0
code to approach a Reverse type is much easier than before, saying

```js
type Reverse<T extends any[], R extends any[] = []> =  ReturnType<T extends [infer F, ...infer L] ? () => Reverse<L,[F,...R]> : () => R>
```

some explanation:

1. direct reference type `Reverse` in typealias `Reverse` will result in circularly references error.
2. wrap `Reverse` type in function type (`()=> Reverse`) will opt-out the circularly references error
3. if type expression could resolve staticly, the compiler will try to resolve it, so  `ReturnType<() => Tup<L,[F,...R]>>` wont do the trick, but
   `ReturnType<ConditionalType>` will do

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

TypeScript 4.1 introduced recursive conditional types.

They allow a tuple reversal function to be implemented like this:

```
type Reverse<Tuple> = Tuple extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest]
       ? [...Reverse<Rest>, Head] : [];

const test: Reverse<[1,2,3,4]> = [4,3,2,1];
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had not thought of just spreading the result of the recursive call. Fantastic idea and I will definitely use this approach more often.

Answer (score 2):

<s>This only works when you know the length of the array:</s>

```
type a = [1,2,3]
type Invert<T extends [any, any, any]> = [T[2], T[1], T[0]];
type b = Invert<a> // should yield [3,2,1]
```

#### Update

Actually there exists a solution (found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901) at an issue of the typescript project):

```ts
export type Prepend<Tuple extends any[], Addend> = 
     ((_: Addend, ..._1: Tuple) => any) extends ((..._: infer Result) => any) ? Result : never;
    
export type Reverse<Tuple extends any[], Prefix extends any[] = []> = {
    0: Prefix;
    1: ((..._: Tuple) => any) extends ((_: infer First, ..._1: infer Next) => any)
        ? Reverse<Next, Prepend<Prefix, First>>
        : never;
}[Tuple extends [any, ...any[]] ? 1 : 0];


type b = Reverse<[1, 2, 3]>; // type b = [3, 2, 1]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKVgoHYBMA8AKgK5gA2qoMweAznAIbaIDaAugDRwCCuuNuAHxwAvHABQcKVIAUMgPoAuHnwFcAdJvkBGZSXLAAlKOFNExqgPpzN6pXACW2AGbAocAErBaxMjGMipszGAPye3r7wytjAAG5uANyS0uKgkLAIyKhe8VC0wESkFHCWdIzM7FwYwM4OICUg1GVm7KJw7MJiAN7JUgAMytW1IEnScLpwNlp6RUYm5eYNTbjWCspOru4AYg55MBpaExtucAByVAFB5r1jcGE5bvn4541VmDgEQ3VcO3uCgjcxtE4olxABfFj6YqlFbtMwHdQtNhsO7jODKPpsJLicRIFBwABGbQeeQKLG0XAATFwAMxsQQJOAAeiZmXxRLELBpVK42jYQA)

Comment: actually, i want to get a generic version

Comment: If you mean a type definition that reverses any number of array entries, this is not possible. As you mentioned above, this requires a head and tail operator, which in turn requires a rest operator in combination with a recursion for generic constrains. Both do not exist for generics.

Comment: @Minami My last comment isn't true, there exists a generic version. See my updated answer.

Comment: @1y1nq nice solution